Getting Column Headers into CSV with Pybaseball
I am trying to import hitting statistics of all MLB batters who played the day before with Pybaseball.  I successfully retrieve all the stats and export it as a CSV, however, I get no column headers so I do not know what all the columns mean.  How can I pull the data with the column headers?  Here is my code:
import pybaseball
from pybaseball import statcast_single_game
from pybaseball import statcast
from pybaseball import batting_stats_bref
import numpy
from pybaseball import batting_stats_range
from pandas import read_csv
from pybaseball import batting_stats

data = batting_stats_range("2024-06-27")
numpy.savetxt('data.csv',data,fmt='%s',delimiter=',')
df = read_csv('data.csv')

Thank you!
Need column headers and it is just importing raw data

You can add the header yourself with the header parameter. Note that by default it would be added as a comment (i.e., a # will be prepended to it), so you need to disable it with the comments parameter:
h = ','.join(data.columns)
numpy.savetxt('data.csv', data, fmt='%s', delimiter=',', header=h, comments='')


I figured it out.  I changed the save part to:
data_selected.to_csv('data.csv',index=False) and that worked
